# Adding Video Element to WebBrowser in Delphi7 with IE9

Tags: html, delphi, delphi-7, twebbrowser

I am working on development of HTML5 editor using delphi7. For this I have added WebBrowser component to my form.

I want to add video element in webbrowser. I have got IE9 and latest MSHTML_TLB.pas *(activex control)*. It shows IHTMLVideo interface in MSHTML_TLB.pas but doesn't display video in webbrowser.

How to add video element to webbrowser?

Comment: What have you tried? Does your video have the right encoding? Does the HTML you have work in IE9, including the video?

Comment: When I write the same video code directly in HTML file and try to run it, it shows the video properly. But not in HTML editor/webbrowser.

Comment: That makes me wonder: Do you actually add exactly the same code. It is essentially the same browser, and as long as you manage to put the right HTML in there, the version of the TLB.pas shouldn't matter, I think.

Comment: It matters because you will get the difference in MSHTML_TLB files when you have IE with lesser than 9 version like IE6 and if you create .pas file from Activex control-- Microsoft HTML Object Library, again with IE9 if you get .pas file, you will get difference like MSHTML_TLB.pas created with IE9 has got interfaces supporting HTML5